# Test Driven Developement for UI components and widgets

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, user-interface, interface

I am building a fairly large JS application in which there are many UI widgets that need to interact with each other.

Since i have used AngularJS for the core, i wanted to implement unit testing for each controller to keep track of their correct behaviour.

Ok.

Now i want to test UI as well, i have use cases that i do manually and look how a component react.

Example:

I have a slider and i load pictures of different sizes in it and each time the slider reloads and restarts it have to contain 4 of them and be of the correct size(s) (according to screen resolution).

What i tought is to use CasperJS and write a testing script to check the box size of the slider on each refresh, then check if all of the elements are there, check the size of them, click on them and so on...

I know this depends a lot from the browser/system but maybe there must be an optimal way to do it.

Mine looks a bit like a hack to me and not elegant, how can i do it better than this? anyone has faced this problem before?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Selenium Webdriver](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/) would be a great tool for this - it will allow you to write scripts to test your UI directly through the browser, and is widely used so there should be plenty of help and advice available for it. Furthermore, it has the added bonus of making it very easy to run your tests against multiple browsers (IE, Firefox, Safari, Chrome all supported).

Personally have found it to be very good for these kind of tests - sure it's a fair amount of effort to put together the tests, and the scripts are often not as clean as one would hope, but at the end of the day it brings a lot of value.